# Multiplayer client has two GameStates

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4, game-state

I'm having struggle with GameState. My custom GameState is child of Game State Base. GameMode (child of Game Mode Base) is updating some variables in my GameState. But my clients have two separate GameStates as illustrated below. First I thought it is normal but now I can see that sometimes first GameState is updated and sometimes the other one. For example, if one of them is updated, then time counter works, but if other one is used, then it is not counting time. I can't figure it out or find any information about it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Game Dev Stack Exchange. Please edit your question to include the code / blueprints relevant to the problem. Without the implementation details, the community can't do much more than make guesses.

Comment: @Pikalek of course, but what will be needed? I'm just printing string in GameState's in this example, showing three variables that should be replicated. I was expecting one string per client/server to be printed and there are two per client.

Comment: I would start with things related to state updates. Things like where the timer data is stored, modified & communicated to the clients. Enough information so that someone else could replicate that basics of the problem. The help page for making a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  has some guidelines.